# Pursuit Curve Modification

Tags: calculus, differential-games

I've been stuck on this problem of **Modified pursuit curve**, in which the dog chases the cat with a constant acceleration $a$, starting from rest. The cat moves horizontally with a uniform speed of $v_0$, and the dog wants to catch the cat at all points of time. The dog is at a distance of $h$ from the cat initially.

What I'm confused about:

> What would be optimal for the dog, acceleration vector always towards the cat, or something else?

What I did: I assumed acceleration vector always towards the cat, and let the dog catch the cat in time $T$. And this is what I'm getting for the equations: $$v_0 T = \int_{0}^{T}{(v \cos{\alpha}) dt}$$ $$h = \int_{0}^{T}{(v \sin{\alpha}) dt} = \int_{0}^{T}{(v_0 \cos{\alpha} - v)}dt$$ I am a beginner in calculus. So can someone correct me/help me with the equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dog should want to travel the least distance, so should compute the point it will catch the cat if it travels on a straight line towards that point.  I assume the cat starts at the origin and travels along the $+x$ axis, while the dog starts at $(0,h)$ and can travel anywhere that is within the allowed acceleration.

The cat's position at time $t$ is $(v_0t,0)$.  In time $t$ the dog can travel $\frac 12at^2$.  For the intercept, we must have $\frac 12at^2=\sqrt{(v_0t)^2+h^2}$ because the dog can cover the distance on the left and needs to cover the distance on the right.  Solve for $t$, then have the dog follow a straight line to the intercept point.  No integral is required.

If the dog always heads at the cat, let $(x(t),y(t))$ be the position of the dog at time $t$.  The cat is at $(v_0t,0)$.  The dog's speed is $v=at$.  The slope of the dog's trajectory is $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac y{v_0t-x}$.  We have $$\frac {dy}{dt}=\frac {dy}{dx}\frac {dx}{dt}=\frac y{v_0t-x}\frac {dx}{dt}\\
at=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac {dx}{dt}\right)^2}\\
at=\frac {dx}{dt}\sqrt {1+\left(\frac y{v_0t-x}\right)^2}$$
but I don't know how to go further

Comment: Because the dog can calculate the point to head for.  It should then accelerate in a straight line towards that point and meet the cat there.  If you substitute $z=t^2$ in the equation I gave and square it, you get a quadratic in $z$ which you can feed to the quadratic formula and find the time of the meeting,$t_i$.  The dog then heads for $(v_0t_i,0)$ and meets the cat there.

Comment: I am assuming the cat is required to run along the $+x$ axis at constant velocity.  If we know that we can do the calculation I suggest. The problem specifies that.  If the cat is free to move differently, the dog's strategy needs to be different.  Given that we know how the cat will move, a straight line lets the dog go a shorter distance, which will result in a shorter time to catch the cat.  People in sports do that all the time-run to where the opponent will be, not where s/he is.

Comment: If the dog is running toward the cat you get differential equations for the dog's position as a function of $t$.  You calculate the speed at any given time, resolve the vector into $x$ and $y$ components, and that gives you $\frac {dx}{dt}$ and $\frac {dy}{dt}$.  The pursuit curve comes up if the dog is too dumb to realize what the cat will do or is worried the cat will change strategy.  It is a different and much harder problem.

Comment: If the dog is dumb, are the differential equations I wrote in the original post correct? And can you please solve them?

Comment: I don't think they are sufficient.  You need something to define $\alpha$ as a function of $t$.  Please show your work, as it is easier to check than to do.

Comment: Umm, these are all the equations I was able to build. I'm not able to find $\alpha(t)$. Once that is done, the problem is finished. Please tell me how to find it and how to solve further.